# Pig capture matching string with regex

Tags: regex, apache-pig

I am trying to capture image url's from inside tweets.

```
REGISTER 'hdfs:///user/cloudera/elephant-bird-pig-4.1.jar';
REGISTER 'hdfs:///user/cloudera/elephant-bird-core-4.1.jar';
REGISTER 'hdfs:///user/cloudera/elephant-bird-hadoop-compat-4.1.jar';

--Load Json

loadJson = LOAD '/user/cloudera/tweetwall' USING com.twitter.elephantbird.pig.load.JsonLoader('-nestedLoad') AS (json:map []);
B = FOREACH loadJson GENERATE flatten(json#'tweets') as (m:map[]);
tweetText = FOREACH B GENERATE FLATTEN(m#'text') as (str:chararray);
```

intermediate date looks like this:

```
(@somenameontwitter your nan makes me laugh with some of the things she comes out with like http://somepics.com/my.jpg)
```

then I try to do the following to get only the image url back :

```
 x = foreach tweetText generate REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL(str, '((http)(.*)(.jpg|.bmp|.png))');

dump x;
```

but that doesn't seem to work. I have also been trying with filter to no avail.

Even when trying the above with .* it returns empty results () or (())

I'm not good with regex and pretty new to Pig so it could be that I'm missing something simple here that I'm just not seeing.

**update**

example input data

```
 {"tweets":[{"created_at":"Sat Nov 01 23:15:45 +0000 2014","id":5286804225,"id_str":"5286864225","text":"@Beace_ your nan makes me laugh with some of the things she comes out with blabla http://t.co/b7hjMWNg is an url, but not a valid one http://www.something.com/this.jpg should be a valid url","source":"\u003ca href=\"http:\/\/twitter.com\/download\/iphone\" rel=\"nofollow\"\u003eTwitter for iPhone\u003c\/a\u003e","truncated":false,"in_reply_to_status_id":52812992878592,"in_reply_to_status_id_str":"522","in_reply_to_user_id":398098,"in_reply_to_user_id_str":"3","in_reply_to_screen_name":"Be_","user":{"id":425,"id_str":"42433395","name":"SAINS","screen_name":"sa3","location":"Lincoln","profile_location":null,"description":"","url":null,"entities":{"description":{"urls":[]}},"protected":false,"followers_count":92,"friends_count":526,"listed_count":0,"created_at":"Mon May 25 16:18:05 +0000 2009","favourites_count":6,"utc_offset":0,"time_zone":"London","geo_enabled":true,"verified":false,"statuses_count":19,"lang":"en","contributors_enabled":false,"is_translator":false,"is_translation_enabled":false,"profile_background_color":"EDECE9","profile_background_image_url":"http:\/\/abs.twimg.com\/images\/themes\/theme3\/bg.gif","profile_background_image_url_https":"https:\/\/abs.twimg.com\/images\/themes\/theme3\/bg.gif","profile_background_tile":false,"profile_image_url":"http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/52016\/DGDCj67z_normal.jpeg","profile_image_url_https":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/526\/DGDCj67z_normal.jpeg","profile_banner_url":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_banners\/424395\/13743515","profile_link_color":"088253","profile_sidebar_border_color":"D3D2CF","profile_sidebar_fill_color":"E3E2DE","profile_text_color":"634047","profile_use_background_image":true,"default_profile":false,"default_profile_image":false,"following":false,"follow_request_sent":false,"notifications":false},"geo":null,"coordinates":null,"place":null,"contributors":null,"retweet_count":0,"favorite_count":1,"entities":{"hashtags":[],"symbols":[],"user_mentions":[{"screen_name":"e_","name":"\u2601\ufe0f effy","id":3998,"id_str":"398","indices":[0,15]}],"urls":[]},"favorited":false,"retweeted":false,"lang":"en"}]}
```

Comment: You want extract the image url from each tweets right? ie,final output should be "http://somepics.com/my.jpg" ?

Comment: Correct, that is what I want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it working (though I doubt it is totally optimal)

```
x = foreach tweetText generate REGEX_EXTRACT(str,'(http://.*(.jpg|.bmp|.png))',1) as image;


filtered = FILTER x BY $0 is not null;


dump filtered;
```

so the initial problem was just the regex (and my lack of knowledge on the subject).

Thanks for the assistance [sivasakthi jayaraman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3027162/sivasakthi-jayaraman)!

Answer (score 1):

Try this and let me know if this works

```
x = foreach tweetText generate REGEX_EXTRACT(str,'.*(http://.*.[jpg|bmp|png])',1);
DUMP x;
```

Comment: that gives me somewhat of a better result, but it's not there yet.
This is some sample of what I get back: `()
(http://t.co/Vbiq6ZuvzB) RT to enter Entran)
()
()
(http://t.co/TQu8XGg)
(http://t.co/EYp)
()
(http://t.co/g0p)
()
(http://t.co/efo13URHBg http)
()
(http://t.co/DJU5KlsiCr http)
()
()
(http://t.co/HUVPF9j)
(http://t.co/iipidujn)
()
()
(http://t.co/Xd6NqApcnC http)
()
()
()
()
()
(http://t.co/tXQT891XA5 http)
()
()
()
(http://t.co/b7hjMWNg)`

Comment: Can you paste your json file. I want to check all the inputs of image url?

Comment: added an example to question

Comment: where is the image url in the json input? you are just printing the value of key "text":"@Beace_ your nan makes me laugh with some of the things she comes out with". This 'text' key doesnt have any image URL. Can you give me more info?

Comment: oh sorry I ll adjust it in a minute. But basically that doesn't matter, any tweet text with a text value containing an image url should be filtered, in this case adding a matching url anywhere in the text should ba caught.

Comment: The above regex script that i pasted will work well for your initial data "(@somenameontwitter your nan makes me laugh with some of the things she comes out with like http://somepics.com/my.jpg)". But your actual data format is something different, you need to give your complete json format.

Comment: https://mega.co.nz/#!hYkHRIwI!__JgTwFxGywO9QtL4ZbnpIhoWZbJ_fpo70hri5tr28I this is an example of some json data